# How can I make an oblique line on a text with HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css, text

How can I make an oblique line on a text by using HTML5 and CSS3?

PS: I suppose that the use of `<canvas>` is a possible way to get the solution.

Comment: U need a line through for the text which is oblique?

Comment: No no! The text is normal, the line must be oblique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using CSS and positioning divs on top of each other and then rotating one of them.

http://jsfiddle.net/jonbrownm/QvDwj/

There is also the * {text-decoration: line-through;} declaration but that won't be oblique.
The solution really needs to be in HTML but I'm not sure of a method of doing this without CSS.